# Issues translating C++ string manipulation to C

Tags: c++, c, string

So I have a small portion of my program that is doing base conversion. In this case from a byte buffer (base 256) to base 58.

I'm trying to translate this portion into C, so that when I need to write other implementations of it I can just reuse the same code.

From the original C++:

```
static unsigned int divide_58(string& x)  {
    const size_t length = x.length();
    size_t pos = 0;
    char *quotient = new char[length];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        const size_t j = i + 1 + x.length() - length;
        if (x.length() < j)
            break;

        const unsigned int value = base2dec(x.c_str(), j);  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both

        quotient[pos] = (unsigned char)(value / 58);
        if (pos != 0 || quotient[pos] != ascii[0])
            pos++;

        size_t len = 4;
        char *temp_str = dec2base(value % 58, len);  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both
        x.replace(0, j, temp_str, len);  //Replace the contents at 0 thru j with the whole contents of temp_str, moving things appropriately
        free(temp_str);
    }

    // calculate remainder
    const unsigned int remainder = base2dec(x.c_str(), x.length());  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both

    // remove leading "zeros" from quotient and store in 'x'
    x.assign(quotient, quotient + pos);

    return remainder;
}
```

I translated this to the following bit of C:

```
static unsigned int divide_58(char *x, size_t &length)  {
    const size_t const_length = length;
    size_t pos = 0;
    char *quotient = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * const_length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < const_length; ++i) {
        const size_t j = i + 1 + length - const_length;
        if (length < j)
            break;

        const unsigned int value = base2dec(x, j);  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both

        quotient[pos] = (unsigned char)(value / 58);
        if (pos != 0 || quotient[pos] != ascii[0])
            pos++;

        size_t len = 4;
        char *temp_str = dec2base(value % 58, len);  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both
        memcpy(x, temp_str, len);
        free(temp_str);

        memmove(x + len, x + j, length - j);
        length -= j;
        length += len;
    }

    // calculate remainder
    const unsigned int remainder = base2dec(x, length);  //defined elsewhere; consistent in both

    // remove leading "zeros" from quotient and store in 'x'
    memcpy(x, quotient, pos);
    free(quotient);
    length = pos;

    return remainder;
}
```

This works in almost all cases, but on my Linux testing environment (and none of my local machines) it produces the wrong answer, despite agreeing that the input is correct.

Failing example: https://app.shippable.com/runs/57cf7ae56f908e0e00c5e451/1/console (build_ci -> make cpytest cov=true)

Working example: https://travis-ci.org/gappleto97/p2p-project/jobs/158036360#L392

I know that the standard is to provide the shortest example of the problem, but as near as I can tell this *is* the shortest example. Can y'all help me out?

For the MCVE folks, you can verify this yourself via my git repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/gappleto97/p2p-project
cd p2p-project
git checkout develop
make cpytest
git checkout c_issue
rm -r build
make cpytest
```

The first call to make will have failing tests. The second will not. The second is using the C++ code provided here, the first is using the C code provided here. It's been bumped up to Python for ease of testing, but I've narrowed it down to this function. That will probably be useless though because I can only replicate the bug on Shippable.

Comment: There is no MCVE. `dec2base` and `base2dec` are not in there. The code is not **C**, needs C++ compiler to compile. `memcpy` copies within the buffer itself. use `memmove`.

Comment: ^ very true above no MCVE

Comment: You do need to improve the question concerning no MCVE. Which includes details of the problem like what you are finding when you are debugging it

Comment: `char *quotient = new char[const_length];` - is that C code? Further - isn't it a memory leak?

Comment: This is the best I can get on an MCVE. It's coming down to an issue that I can't replicate anywhere else, and this is the narrowest I've managed to get it, despite trying other ways to narrow it.

As for the new bit: Yes that's not C. Looks like I forgot to translate a bit there. Yes it's a memory leak. This is new-ish code that wasn't expected to be used in production quite yet, so I'm not terribly surprised I didn't catch it. I just fixed that in the C version (since the C++ version is hopefully going to be removed anyways).

Comment: @gabeappleton You mean it's the best you can get to an ME. You missed the C and V parts.

Comment: Added some stuff for that. Probably not everything you want, but I don't really know how to do better on this front without pasting a good deal of code into here.

Comment: is `dec2base` supposed to be modifying its `len` arg to say how many characters it actually produced? Because it can't do that in C unless you pass a pointer.

Comment: It is. It seems to be doing so correctly as well. That said, I just updated everything to follow your critique, and it now compiles in a C compiler, not just a C++ one. I actually hadn't tested that before.

Comment: You *really* perform a malloc and free `length` times rather than passing a buffer to base2dec???? Further, I would remind you that C is not a subset of C++, it's a separate language that has evolved along its own track since it birthed C++ over 30 years ago. And that catches people out. Honestly, what you've written is not C, it's dumbed down bad C++. I would encourage you to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get proper conversion assistance if the quality of the code matters to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have translated this C++ line:

```
    x.replace(0, j, temp_str, len);
```

into this C code:

```
    memcpy(x, temp_str, len);
    memmove(x + len, x + j, length - j);
    length -= j;
    length += len;
```

That is not equivalent code.

One thing is that you never add a zero-termination to `x`.

Another thing is that the code produce completely different strings when `j` is less than 4.

Look at this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "abcdefgh";
    char t[10] = "01234567";
    cout << "Original: " << s << endl;

    int j = 2;

    // The c++ way
    s.replace(0, j, t, 4);
    cout << "C++: " << s << endl;

    // Your C way
    char x[10] = "abcdefgh";
    size_t length = strlen(x);
    memcpy(x, t, 4);
    memmove(x + 4, x + j, length - j);
    cout << "C  : " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> Original: abcdefgh
>
> C++: 0123cdefgh
>
> C  : 012323efgh

The same code with `j = 6`:

> Output:
>
> Original: abcdefgh
>
> C++: 0123gh
>
> C  : 0123ghgh

**Conclusion** Your C code for C++ replace is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try and come up with a better translation of string::replace.